# MOSFET Gate driver - negative voltage with Zener circuit

Tags: voltage, mosfet, negative

I was reading about minimizing MOSFET switching loss when I came across an article by Texas Instrument on how to use negative voltage, instead of ground, to faster discharge MOSFET gate capacitance. To create the split voltage (say, +20 V/-5 V to charge/discharge C<sub>gs</sub>), one of the schematics uses Zener circuit like below:

[image: Texas Instrument ucc21520]

In TI description, *"If the isolated power supply, VA, is equal to 25 V, the turn-off voltage will be –5.1 V and turn-on voltage will be 25 V – 5.1 V ≈ 20 V... and there will be steady state power consumption from R<sub>z</sub>."* Can R<sub>z</sub> be removed from the circuit?

Question solved by further reading into "Zener diode voltage stabilizer/regulator". Thank you for reading!

Comment: The Rz is a must. It allows the minimal current flow through the diode, so that it stabilises the voltage. It's a very basic zener diode voltage stabiliser, you can search on the web for this question.

Comment: Thank you for your suggested keyword of "zener diode voltage stabiliser".

Comment: You can also look for TIDA that has a little bit rearranged schematics and good explanation on  this split power supply: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidue55a/tidue55a.pdf

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Your comment is the answer, though?